# Function generator directly from power on to use

Tags: function-generator

I'm using a function generator. When I power it on, I need to push a button so I can use it (AFG 3022.) Is it possible to do something (the settings says nothing about this) so when I power ON it directly passes the standby stage and can be used without pressing the button?

Comment: That's probably a question for the manufacturer, unless it has a remote command interface you could drive from an MCU or PC.  Perhaps this is an XY problem in the sense that rather than use that instrument, maybe what you really need is just a reliable hands-off-start way to generate the needed signal.  So what _is_ the needed signal, exactly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, the needed signal is to push a button for 1,5-2 seconds once the power is On, Probably will send a message to the manufacturer because even if it doesnt appear in the manual I thing that must be able to control from an interface or something, thanks!

Comment: I wasn't asking what you need to do to get the function generator to produce output, I was asking what the generator is *for*.  Chances are there's a cheaper way to generate the output it generates which implicitly runs right away from power on.  In terms of if it has an interface, look on the back panel and check the manual...

Comment: That appears to be primitive solution for a UPS.  I'm sure the manual indicates a solution.  Why have you NOT read it?

Comment: Hi, i have read the 461pages manual and says nothing about that, only says that is necessary to push the button so the function generator goes from standby to ON, I'm using a program made by me for remote control but to send commands and query it has to be power on, which only can be if I push the button